# ngCordova $cordovaZip not unzipping, Ionic app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I've been struggling for the past couple hours with trying to unzip a specific .epub file using $cordovaZip but witouth any luck.

The zip and file plugins are installed properly, also $cordovaZip is injected to the specific controller. When i'm trying to unzip a local/remote .epub file I just get the error callback instead of the success one.

Here is a sample of my code.

```
$cordovaZip
.unzip(
'/templates/test.epub'
cordova.file.dataDirectory).then(function (data) {
  console.log('success', data);
}, function (err) {
  console.log('error', err);
}, function (progressEvent) {
  // https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/zip#usage
  console.log(progressEvent);
});
```

I would appreciate if anyone who encountered the same issue could give me a hand..

Answer (score 0):

I believe an absolute URL is required and not a relative URL.
e.g.

```
var PathToFileInString  = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory+"HereIsMyFolder",
    PathToResultZip     = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory;
JJzip.zip(PathToFileInString, {target:PathToResultZip,name:"SuperZip"},function(data){
    /* Wow everiting goes good, but just in case verify data.success*/
},function(error){
    /* Wow something goes wrong, check the error.message */
})
```

Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-zip-plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$cordovaZip.unzip(
    '/templates/test.zip',
    cordova.file.dataDirectory + extracted_file_name
).then(
    function (data) {
      console.log('success', data);
    }
);
```